# Javascript recursions. Why the following code works with .unshift() instead of .push()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, console.log

My brain believes that I should use `.push()` instead of `.unshift()` but freeCodeCamp and my console tell that this is the right way of doing it. I just don't understand how come my numbers go from 10 to 20 using `.unshift()`, and 20 to 10 using `.push()`;

The way I read the code:
if `startNum` is bigger than `endNum` return an empty array. Otherwise, create a variable called `arr` and assign to it the current `startNum` increased by 1 each time the code runs and return it into the array.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (startNum > endNum) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);
    arr.unshift(startNum);
    return arr;
  }
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(10, 20));
```

The console: `(11) [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`

Comment: In a recursive manner, the last call added to the stack called first. So if you try to use push instead of unshift you will add the last value first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think of it is to imagine that the recursive call already worked properly.  So `rangeOfNumbers(11, 20)` would yield `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`.  And so  `const arr = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum)` means that `arr` is `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`.  Now you have `startNum` and `arr` and need to combine them.  `push` would add `startNum` to the end.  `unshift` properly adds it to the beginning.

But while we're here, I'd like to suggest a more elegant way to express that same algorithm:

```js
const rangeOfNumbers = (start, end) => 
  start > end 
    ? []
    : [start, ... rangeOfNumbers (start + 1, end)]
```

Instead of `if-else` statements we have a single conditional expression.  And we don't mutate a variable like `arr` in the process.  I think it also more cleanly expresses the algorithm.  Of course tastes may vary, and, if you're just learning JS, this may involve syntax you haven't seen yet.  But if you do understand it, you might agree with me about its elegance.

Answer (score 1):

`unshift` inserts an element into the beginning of the array.

Since you're iterating from the `startNum` to the `endNum`, consider the next to last recursive call:

```
const arr = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);
arr.unshift(startNum);
return arr;
```

where `startNum` is 19 and `endNum` is 20. The recursive call returns an array with one element: `[20]`. Then you need to insert the `19` element in the proper position.

To do this, you'll need to insert the 19 at the beginning, to get:

```
[19, 20]
```

So, insert 19 at the beginning with `unshift`.

If you used `push` instead, from the original `[20]`, you'd get:

```
[20, 19] // 19 added to end
```

and then

```
[20, 19, 18] // 18 added to end
```

and so on, which isn't in the right order.

You could use `push` if you inserted elements *before* the recursive call.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum, arr = []) {
  arr.push(startNum);
  if (startNum < endNum) {
    rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum, arr);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(10, 20));
```